# How Azure Search stores the index data

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have a lot of data stored in Azure Search. And I'm too greedy so decided to understand how the index data is stored to predict its size and service costs.

*Spoiler:* `According to the experiment field name length does not impact the storage used for the index`

**Input (examples at the end)**

1. Data structure with `Id` + 9 string fields. All fields have long names. Name length to data length is `24 to 37`

   Record example:

   ```
   {
       "Id": "55bd7474-1e48-464c-a54d-bc2f3d8b0383",
       "MySuperLongNameProperty": "0e2c5f5e-9464-4030-bf3f-9de41181faff",
       "MySuperLongName2Property": "aa521300-1925-4dd6-97f2-f27fed1b720e",
       "MySuperLongName3Property": "9eec9f1f-d970-4581-8677-92cd735c9d80",
       "MySuperLongName4Property": "e3b4619b-bb8c-4fa2-82b2-55287f4262ae",
       "MySuperLongName5Property": "e6b79880-650d-4733-b91a-e5a4e066811d",
       "MySuperLongName6Property": "d391c66c-f3c6-45e2-96ef-80ab682fa07b",
       "MySuperLongName7Property": "62a92d68-74e6-41b1-8f92-ac3795b649cd",
       "MySuperLongName8Property": "83510497-a6b0-4d6e-9130-0f8deefd73db",
       "MySuperLongName9Property": "977e397e-5fc9-4677-afaf-52b9ea0a8f23"
   }
   ```
2. Data structure with `Id` + 9 string fields. All fields have short names. Name length to data length is `3 to 37`

   Record example:

   ```
   {
       "Id": "f403f9ce-b343-4e38-bc4b-24d300eb13fb",
       "mp": "10970b17-62fe-431a-bf4f-d5a17266c4dc",
       "m2p": "b338290b-069b-4494-8c9e-8da85aad0990",
       "m3p": "1be76d7f-07d2-4648-9888-ed15ec7b3857",
       "m4p": "327206c8-561c-4651-95e0-06c58f83739a",
       "m5p": "241b2be7-9aac-41f9-b669-c5c768acd42e",
       "m6p": "55a1691a-d525-442e-b369-380d2480f2b1",
       "m7p": "a1263c81-022b-4f59-97fe-8916e1457d35",
       "m8p": "b4a4819b-185b-46ab-8e34-838fbc8a598a",
       "m9p": "38bc1df8-81cf-4005-bb14-2fe8a1c6797a"
   }
   ```

**Experiments**

For each experiment I used Guid data to populate all fields (.NET `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`).

Also, experiments are executed as N batches * 1000 items:

```
let insert<'t> (client: ISearchIndexClient) (docs: 't list) =
        let actions = docs |> Seq.ofList |> Seq.map(fun x -> IndexAction.Upload x) |> Seq.cast<IndexAction<'t>>
        let batch = IndexBatch.New(actions)
        client.Documents.Index batch |> ignore

for x in [1..1000] do
  let batch = [1..1000] |> List.map(fun i -> {.. generate record ..})
  insert batch
```

So, some numbers:

1. Adding 1.2M records to index

   Long name storage size: 1.68Gb

   Short name storage size: 1.65Gb
2. Add 3M records to index

   Long name storage size: 5.53Gb (~2Gb raw JSON text data)

   Short name storage size: 4.11Gb (~1.5Gb raw JSON text data)

   After 10-20 minutes, suddenly, the overall size was reduced automatically

   Long name storage size: 4.04Gb

   Short name storage size: 4.06Gb

Originally, I expected to see the behavior described [here](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Field-name-size-and-index-size-td553525.html). But after the 2nd experiment the size difference was significant (the index was not compressed yet).

After all, I assume there are few strategies on how to store the index data. Maybe for small indexes field names are compressed automatically. While for larger ones it stores as is, but schedules the background service for further compression.

**As result, as far as I can see there is no difference in fields naming as the length of field name will not impact the storage size**

Any thoughts or explanations?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the name you give to your fields should generally have a negligible impact on the overalls size of your index. Each of the document's field exist on disk under multiple different forms (depending on which features are enable for that field, such as searchable, filterable, sortable, etc.). Most of those forms are heavily optimized to serve their specific needs, and in most cases, the field names don't need to be included in the files that contains them. However, the full json original documents are also stored alongside the indexed versions (so the document can be retrieved). Since the "original" documents will include the field names, technically, there will be some linear correlation between the length of the fields and the overall size of your index, however, the correlation should have a pretty weak coefficient. The best way to verify what is that coefficient is through tests (which you have already done), since each uses cases will be different.

Comment: so for the index all names are shortened during the indexing. And there is also a background service which compresses all original JSON docs?

Comment: No the index names are not shortened during indexing. Also, there's no "compressing" of original JSON docs. You should assume that documents you push to the service will actually have a larger footprint in the index than the size of the original documents. As I mentioned in my answer, when you push a document, that document will be heavily analyzed/transformed and will exist under multiple forms within the index (including the original form). So its size on disk will be the original size (since we keep the original document) plus the size of all the additional format that it got transformed in

Comment: Without knowing exactly what step you took in your test, its hard to give you an explanation as to why your index sized varied  after 10-20 minutes. The general explanation is that every single file in the index is "read-only". As you modify your index (updating, deleting, adding documents), we mark some of the older files for "future deletion" as they become obsolete. There's a background service that will eventually delete those files as well as merge some others to improve the performance of your index. Through that, the index size might get smaller without your direct involvement.

Comment: I have insert-only records in my test, so nothing is recycled (I assume). As I understand the overall index size should be `original data size` + `indexed data size` (where indexed data depends on configuration e.g. searchable, sortable fields, etc). Thus I assume for exactly the same amount of records which differs in field name length there should be a difference in index size. but according to my test there is no difference. and it looks like the original data was compressed. original data size is specified in test 2 - it's 540B and 730B * 1.2M and 3M records. so there should be difference

Comment: As mentioned previously, as you insert files into your index, a background worker merge/delete files in the index. Even if you only "insert" new documents, various files in your index will need to be deleted and re-created. For example, all texts statistics (such as document frequency) need to be updated to include newly added documents. The merging schedule is really hard to predict as it depends on many factors such as resource utilization, ingestion rate, etc. You could re-create the exact same index using the exact same data and have slightly different size each time.

Comment: sounds weird. how can it be different output for the same input? anyway I have input data 1.5Gb and 3Gb. Data contains absolutely the same values, but in first case I have 3 symbol firld names, while in second ~25. And index size for both of them is the same - 4Gb. So I assume that field name length does not fluent on index size (not more than 1-5%)